# Sequence in $(0,1)$ without accumulation points

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, soft-question

In $\mathbb R$, a subset is compact in and only if it is closed and bounded. The open interval $A=(0,1)$ is not closed so is not compact. Hence there must exist a sequence $\{a_n\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$ without cluster points (otherwise $A$ would be compact). Is it possible to find such a sequence?

It should be easy since the sequence has countable many points where the open interval is uncountable, but I can't find any sequence. On the other hand, after having a look at [If $X$ is not countably compact, then there exists a countable subset without accumulation points](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/675182/if-x-is-not-countably-compact-then-there-exists-a-countable-subset-without-ac), I'm not sure this is possible, because $A$ is countable compact, isn't it?

**Motivation.** I'm studing sequential spaces and I was wondering how the definition of sequentially open is modifed when you allow the sequence to have no limit points. I have included the tag `soft question`because I'm not really worried about that. It's out of curiosity.

Thanks

Comment: Any sequence in $(0,1)$ which is convergent to $0$ or $1$ elements of $\bar{A}\setminus A$ (cluster points outside $A$).

Comment: Mmmm yes. It was obvious, wasn't it? Anyway, thanks.

Comment: What do you mean? Did I misunderstood your question?

Comment: @RobertZ No no. But thanks to your comments I have realized that it was an stupid question. But your answer is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sequence defined by $a_n = \frac{1}{n}$ for $n \geq 2$ is a sequence of $(0,1)$ that has no accumulation point in $(0,1)$.